# Does setattr make a deepcopy?

Tags: python, deep-copy, shallow-copy, setattr

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr From this documentation, I cannot tell if a deep copy is made or not.

I'm working with a codebase currently that uses `setattr` is a rather disgusting way.

Here is the relevant snippet from the constructor of a class:

```
    for var in vars:
      # ExtMang is another class
      setattr(self, var, ExtMang(self))
    # create an alias
    for var in vars :
      if var.endswith("_modified") :
        setattr(self, var[:-9], getattr(self, var))
```

I'm mostly a C++ guy, so I don't know how common/acceptable this is to do in python, but this snippet looks awful to me.

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if any unmodified var is a deepcopy or a reference to the modified var. e.g., say `vars = ["price_modified"]`. In the first loop, `price_modified` would be set as an attribute of self. In the second loop, it would set `price` as an attribute of `self`. I'm trying to figure out if `self.price` is a deepcopy or reference of `self.price_modified`

Comment: Nothing in Python copies automatically. If you want a copy you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar I see, so in this case, `self.price` is just a reference of `self.price_modified` ? and modifying `self.price` would therefore also modify the latter?

Comment: Yes, if the value is a mutable object, and you modify that object, you'll see it in both attributes.

Comment: got it. also, what exactly is "explicitly" and does it apply to only non-POD types? e.g., if I do "b = 2" then "a = b". is this considered "explicit?" because in this case, `a` is clearly a copy and not of `b` and not a reference

Comment: Explicit is using a function like `copy.deepcopy()` or `list.copy()`.

Comment: This is only relevant for mutable types. Integers are immutable, so it doesn't matter whether a copy is made or not.

Comment: So explicit would be `setattr(self, var[:-9], copy.deepcopy(getattr(self, var)))`

Comment: "what exactly is "explicitly" and does it apply to only non-POD types?" Python has **no concept like** "POD type". Every value has **reference semantics**; at the implementation level, it is indirected behind a pointer. `a = b` **does not** copy `b`, **even if** `b` is an integer; it makes `a` and `b` both be names for the same integer object. (Because it is **not possible to change the internal state of this object from within Python**, you will not observe any aliasing. Something like `a += 1` will **create or reuse a new object** and rebind it to `a`.)

Comment: (Please see the linked duplicate for details.) As an aside, yes, `setattr` is not common and usually not justified; the way to avoid it is to store the values in a `dict` instead.